# How do you install third-party apps on iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, automated-tests, ios-simulator

I am building an app that uses oauth as a step of its sign-up process (specifically TikTok's). You can see the documentation on how to do this here: https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/login-kit-ios-login-kit-with-swift

We want to write automated UI tests, but don't know how to install TikTok on the simulator to test our app. As a result, we've come up with a hacky solution: when you are using the app in the simulator, it fakes the oauth part and assumes everything worked correctly.

I'd like to get rid of that hacky solution and test our actual sign-up flow. But to do so, the simulator would need TikTok installed. I've researched how to do this, and the solutions I found require a binary of the app you want to install built to run on the simulator. I haven't been able to find such a TikTok binary.

Does that mean I've hit a dead end? If so, what are my options? Is there any other way to TikTok install on the simulator?

Comment: You have hit a dead end. You would need a simulator build of the TikTok app and they aren't going to give it to you. Generally for unit tests you would mock the external entity and have that mock provide both success and fail responses. Integration testing you can do manually on a real device.

Comment: "Integration testing you can do manually on a real device." I can, but I absolutely don't want to. I need to automate.

Comment: There are services that let you run tests on real devices in the cloud, but you are never going to be able to do it in the simulator if you have a dependency on an external app.

Comment: @DanielKaplan You could check to authenticate via web APIs. If simulator then API else via TikTok App.